# Conditional assignment to multiple columns in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

How can I make a conditional assignment to multiple columns in polars if I have an external condition and a list of columns to assign to?  In my example I have:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4],
                   'b':[10,20,30,40,50],
                   'c':[100,200,300,400,500]})
```

Which gives:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 10  ┆ 100 │
│ 1   ┆ 20  ┆ 200 │
│ 2   ┆ 30  ┆ 300 │
│ 3   ┆ 40  ┆ 400 │
│ 4   ┆ 50  ┆ 500 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

and

```
condition = [True, False, False, False, True]
columns = ['a', 'c']
```

In pandas, I might have used a state like

```
df.loc[condition, columns] = None
```

How can I do this in polars?

And gotten:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ None   ┆ 10  ┆ None │
│ 1   ┆ 20  ┆ 200 │
│ 2   ┆ 30  ┆ 300 │
│ 3   ┆ 40  ┆ 400 │
│ None   ┆ 50  ┆ None │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the condition a one-time `Series` in a `pl.when` (in this specific case for the given output, I inversed the condition so the `otherwise(null)` default would kick in):

```py
df.with_columns(pl.when(~pl.Series(condition)).then(pl.col(columns)))
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ 10  ┆ null │
│ 1    ┆ 20  ┆ 200  │
│ 2    ┆ 30  ┆ 300  │
│ 3    ┆ 40  ┆ 400  │
│ null ┆ 50  ┆ null │
└──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, would appreciate confirmation, but this seems to be the way:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(~pl.Series(condition))
    .then(pl.col(columns))
    .otherwise(None)
)
```

produces:

```
a   b   c
i64 i64 i64
null    10  null
1   20  200
2   30  300
3   40  400
null    50  null
```